# Why is this identity involving vector valued functions true?

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus

I am reading about stationary harmonic maps and I came across the following calculation.

Let $\mathcal{Q}_t(x) = x+ t\zeta(x),$ where $\zeta\in C^{\infty}_c(B_{\rho}(x_0), \mathbb{R}^n)$ where $x_0\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $\rho>0.$ We choose $|t|$ small enough such that $\mathcal{Q}_t$ is a diffeomorphism of $B_{\rho}(x_0)$ onto itself. Then I don't understand why the following identities hold.

\begin{align} 
D \mathcal{Q}_{t}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{Q}_{t}(x)\right) &= I-t D \zeta(x)+O\left(t^{2}\right) \\ 
\operatorname{det} D \mathcal{Q}_{t}(x) &=1+t \operatorname{div} \zeta(x)+O\left(t^{2}\right) \end{align}

Any hints/references suggesting how to prove the above two identities will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since $DQ_t=I+tD\xi$, the two formulas follow from the following two facts:

- If $Inv:GL(\mathbf{R}^n)\to GL(\mathbf{R}^n)$ is the inversion, then
  $$D(Inv)_I[A]=-A;$$
- The differential of the determinant at the identity is
  $$D(\det)_{I}[A]=\operatorname{tr}(A).$$

Answer (score 0):

- For the first identity, by the inverse function theorem we have that, $DQ_t^{-1}(Q_t(x)) = (DQ_t)^{-1}(x)=I -tD\zeta(x) +O(t^2).$
- For the second identity, we can use the fact, $\det(I+tB)=I+t\operatorname{Tr}(B)+O(t^2)$ and $DQ_t = I+tD\zeta$ where $I$ is the Identity matrix. Then we simply replace the matrix $B$ with the Jacobian matrix $D\zeta$, which gives us the second expression.